# C# - Specified cast is not valid using DataTable and Field<int>

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, casting

I have a csv file with 8 columns, and I am trying to populate an object with 8 variables, each being a list to hold the columns in the csv file. Firstly, I am populating a `DataTable` with my csv data.

I am now trying to populate my object with the data from the `DataTable`

```
DataTable d = GetDataTableFromCSVFile(file);
CoolObject l = new CoolObject();

for (int i = 0; i < d.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    l.column1[i] = d.Rows[i].Field<int>("column1"); <-- error here
}
```

And here is my `CoolObject`

```
public class CoolObject
{
    public List<int> column1 { set; get; }

    protected CoolObject()
    {
        column1 = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am receiving an error on the highlighted line:

`System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid`

Why is this not allowed? How do I work around it?

Comment: Required information for answering your question is code of `GetDataTableFromCSVFile` method, please show it.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you `DataTable` contains columns of type string, so do integer validation in `GetDataTableFromCSVFile` method, so consumers of this method don't need to worry about it.

Obviously you `DataTable` contains columns of type string, so do integer validation in `GetDataTableFromCSVFile` method, so consumers of this method don't need to worry about it.

```
private DataTable GetDataTableFromCSVFile()
{
    var data = new DataTable();
    data.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int));

    // Read lines of file

    // line is imaginery object which contains values of one row of csv data
    foreach(var line in lines) 
    {
        var row = data.NewRow();
        int.TryParse(line.Column1Value, out int column1Value)
        row.SetField("Column1", column1Value) // will set 0 if value is invalid

        // other columns
    }

    return data;
}
```

Then another problem with your code, that you assugn new values to `List<int>` through index, where list is empty

```
l.column1[i] = d.Rows[i].Field<int>("column1");
```

Above line will throw exception because empty list doesn't have item on index `i`.

So you in the end your method will look

```
DataTable d = GetDataTableFromCSVFile(file);
CoolObject l = new CoolObject();

foreach (var row in d.Rows)
{
    l.column1.Add(row.Field<int>("column1"));
}
```

In case you are using some third-party library for retrieving data from csv to `DataTable` - you can check if that library provide possibility to validate/convert string values to expected types in DataTable.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like someone didn't enter a number in one of the cells. You'll have to perform a validation check before reading the value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < d.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    object o = d.rows[i]["column1"];
    if (!o is int) continue;
    l.column1[i] = (int)o;
}
```

Or perhaps it is a number but for some reason is coming through as a string. You could try it this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < d.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    int n;
    bool ok = int.TryParse(d.rows[i]["column1"].ToString(), out n);
    if (!ok) continue;
    l.column1[i] = n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions John, I will try both of your suggestions